# Oracle procedure insert into table from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, insert

I have this code from trigger and now i need to create procedure because i cant use trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LIVE_MATCHES_TO_MATCHES 
    instead of insert ON LIVE_MATCHES
   for each row
declare
   p_priority number:= 1;
   p_sport number:=0;
   begin
     insert into matches(sub_list , priority , sport, created) 

     select :new.comp_name , p_priority, p_sport,sysdate
     from dual
      where not exists (      
     select 1 from matches
    where sub_list = :new.comp_name);

   end;
```

this is procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LIVE_MATCHES_SOCCER_T IS 
       p_priority number := 1;
   p_sport number:=0;   
begin
INSERT INTO matches("sub_list","priority","sport","created")
SELECT LIVE_MATCHES.COMP_NAME,p_priority,p_sport, sysdate
FROM  LIVE_MATCHES WHERE LIVE_MATCHES.COMP_NAME <> matches.SUB_LIST;
commit;
end;
```

but I m getting error that matches.sub_list is invalid identifier. 
How will i create procedure that will insert into table only if sub_list is different from comp_name.. I will set up job that will call this procedure every 5 minutes..

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Why have you added double quotes on column names in the procedure ?Get rid of them.

Comment: COMP_NAME IS varchar column which is in external table and is automatically inserted in it . Now i need  it to be inserted into MATCHES table by procedure ... only if comp_name is != matches.sub_list. 
I dont know what sample to give you, i think that is irrelevant for this case.

Comment: I tried with and without qoutes its the same error.

Comment: You need a mix of both answers. Use Gordon's solution, but remove double quotes on all columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MERGE statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE PR_INSRT_INTO_MATCHES
IS
  P_PRIORITY NUMBER := 1;
  P_SPORT    NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO MATCHES M USING
  (SELECT DISTINCT COMP_NAME AS COMP_NAME FROM LIVE_MATCHES
  ) LM ON (LM.COMP_NAME=M.SUB_LIST)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (
      M.SUB_LIST,
      M.PRIORITY,
      M.SPORT,
      M.CREATED
    )
    VALUES
    (
      LM.COMP_NAME,
      P_PRIORITY,
      P_SPORT,
      SYSDATE
    )
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: This is working just now how will I in this procedure select union because now i need to merge in to matches from more tables ?

Comment: like this : 
 p_priority number := 1;
   p_sport number := 0;
   p_sport_b number :=1;
   p_sport_t number :=2;
   p_sport_h number :=3;   
begin
  INSERT INTO MATCHES (SUB_LIST, PRIORITY, SPORT, CREATED)
        select lm.COMP_NAME, p_priority,p_sport, sysdate  
        from LIVE_MATCHES lm, MATCHES m WHERE lm.COMP_NAME <> m.SUB_LIST group by lm.COMP_NAME
        union
        select LB.comp_name, p_priority,p_sport_b, sysdate 
        from LIVE_BASKETBALL LB,MATCHES m where lb.comp_name <> m.sub_list group by lb.comp_name;

Comment: to insert data from multiple source tables into matches table , you can either use multiple merge statement or can convert the query "SELECT DISTINCT COMP_NAME AS COMP_NAME FROM LIVE_MATCHES" into a union sql

Comment: I do some edit in your post could you see where do problem is ? Thanks

Comment: How will I protect value M.SUB_LIST if its null not to insert that record ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
INSERT INTO matches("sub_list","priority","sport","created")
    SELECT lm.COMP_NAME, lm.p_priority, lm.p_sport, sysdate
    FROM LIVE_MATCHES lm 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM matches m
                      WHERE lm.COMP_NAME <> m.SUB_LIST
                     );
```

Comment: I am getting error matches.sub_list invalid identifier.

Comment: @civesuas_sine . . . Your original query implies that `matches` has that column . . . `select 1 from matches where sub_list = :new.comp_name`.

Comment: When i run this select alone 0 rows created... so it doesnt insert any rows though there are different comp_names in live_matches

Answer (score 0):

Unless your column names are lower-case (which can only be done in Oracle by using quotes when you create them - and which is not a particularly good idea in any case), then your stored procedure won't work, as you're quoting lower-case identifiers in it. Try this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LIVE_MATCHES_SOCCER_T IS 
   p_priority number := 1;
   p_sport number := 0;   
begin
    INSERT INTO matches
      ( sub_list, priority, sport, created )
    SELECT LIVE_MATCHES.COMP_NAME, p_priority, p_sport, sysdate
      FROM live_matches
     WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM matches WHERE LIVE_MATCHES.COMP_NAME = matches.SUB_LIST );
    commit;
  end;
```

Comment: I am getting error matches.sub_list invalid identifier.

Comment: Try it now, the error is probably from the malformed query which I did not see the first time around.

Comment: When i run this select alone 0 rows created... so it doesnt insert any rows though there are different comp_names in live_matches

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Comment: What exactly do you need ?

Comment: I would love to see what the non-matching data look like - hard to troubleshoot without knowing that